# Jquery DataTables，example code， the header is not showing

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

Following the documentation example, but the header is not showing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="datatable"></table>

        <script>
            var data = [
                {"Province": "Quebec", "Party": "NDP", "Age": 22, "Name": "Liu, Laurin", "Gender": "Female"},
                {"Province": "Quebec", "Party": "Bloc Quebecois", "Age": 43, "Name": "Mourani, Maria", "Gender": "Female"},
                {"Province": "Quebec", "Party": "NDP", "Age": "", "Name": "Sellah, Djaouida", "Gender": "Female"},
                {"Province": "Quebec", "Party": "NDP", "Age": 72, "Name": "St-Denis, Lise", "Gender": "Female"}
            ];

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#datatable').DataTable({
                    data: data,
                    columns: [
                        { data: 'Province' },
                        { data: 'Party' },
                        { data: 'Age' },
                        { data: 'Name' }
                    ],
                    fixedHeader: {
                        header: true,
                        footer: true
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuIVz.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKVPH.png)

I'm going crazy and don't know what's wrong.

Please help me, thank you!

My browser is chrome 97.0.4692.71

Comment: To be pedantic: both your images show the table header.  Just they don't have any text.

Comment: Pls make your question title and body more descriptive. We may be able to help you better if u do. And also, how is this question related to CSS?

Comment: Can you also provide a link directly to the example you're trying? (as there's 100s)

Comment: You need to pass one more object  **title: 'Header Text'** like columns: [{ data: 'Province', title: 'Province' }]

Comment: Or provide a header in the markup: `<thead>
<tr>
<th>Province</th>
<th>Party</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>`  https://jsfiddle.net/7g1btwpa/

Comment: @freedomn-m Why do u need a direct link to the example? You can just use the code he/she posted..

Comment: @ArchitGargi most times when someone says "I did this example", they simply missed something from the example.  If we have the example, we can compare what they've provided here against the example; most times that comparison provides a glaring omission, such as "you've missed the `thead`" or "you've missed the `title: ''`.  *Or* they're using unofficial documentation, known to have misleading content, such as w3schools and we can direct them to the official documentation, but no point doing that if they are already using the official documentation.

Comment: Can you still provide a link to your sample doc?

Comment: Yes of course,   https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't got a `<th>` in the HTML - so there is no heading. If you want to create it with a title, use `columns.title`:

```
                    columns: [
                      { data: 'Province', title: 'province' },
                        { data: 'Party', title: 'party' },
                        { data: 'Age', title: 'age' },
                        { data: 'Name', title: 'name' }
                    ],
```

See your example here: http://live.datatables.net/lecaqufa/1/edit

Comment: Wow, that does solve the problem.
The sample docs fail to provide this information, leading me to oversight.
Thank you so much.

Comment: In the installation section (https://datatables.net/manual/installation) it does say: "For DataTables to be able to enhance an HTML table, the table must be valid, well formatted HTML, with a header (`thead`) and a single body (`tbody`). An optional footer (`tfoot`) can also be used." - your table was missing that information.